# How to select min after selecting max

Tags: sql, max, min

I have to select the lowest status from products after selecting the highest status of each of them. My query is

```
select A. Name
B.LineState
from table A
join table B on A.id=B.refid
where B.Linestate = (select max(B2.Linestate) 
                     from table B2 
                     where B.refid=B2.refid)
```

This works fine and gives proper rows. Now I have to select minimum Linestate from what I get before. I have tried:

```
...
where B.Linestate = min((select max(B2.linestate) 
                         from table B2 
                         where B.refid=B2.refid))
```

Unfortunately it does not work. How can I get minimum value from previously selected group of maximum values?

Comment: Did you have trouble getting the CTE to work? If you're not using too many rows, the other answer will work, but in situations with larger data sets, a CTE is much more efficient.

Comment: No I did not have any trouble, however the 'other' answer by D Stanley is much more clear and understandable for me. Both work. Yours seems more sophisiticated. Thanks for help. That's a pity I cannot mark both answers as accepted.

Comment: No worries! It's true that Stanley's is easier to understand, but, as I said, it's a lot less efficient and mine is actually pretty common practice. If you ever end up using code in the real world, by which I mean in a job or a customer's program, there are other solutions and, for scalability and performance reasons, you want to avoid subqueries and cross applies where you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make your first query a subquery:

```
SELECT MIN(LineState) 
FROM
(
    select A. Name
    B.LineState
    from table A
    join table B on A.id=B.refid
    where B.Linestate=(select max(B2.Linestate) from table B2 where B.refid=B2.refid)
)
```

Or if you want the name too:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM
(
    select A. Name
    B.LineState
    from table A
    join table B on A.id=B.refid
    where B.Linestate=(select max(B2.Linestate) from table B2 where B.refid=B2.refid)
)
ORDER BY Linestate
```

Comment: Is there significant difference in server efficiency of these answers? I mean solution SELECT MIN vs WITH GetMax...From GetMax.

Comment: Probably not - unless you're using the CTE in multiple places or recursively the plan should be almost identical to a subquery.

Answer (score 4):

[Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) are a good solution to this problem. They allow you to get the set you want and then immediately pull a subset from there.

```
; WITH GetMaxList AS (
select A. Name
B.LineState
from table A
join table B on A.id=B.refid
where B.Linestate=(select max(B2.Linestate) from table B2 where B.refid=B2.refid)
)

SELECT MIN([Column])
FROM GetMaxList
```

Keep in mind, this is just example code. It won't work if you copy paste it. You'll need to do a little reading to figure out how to tweak your query to get it to do what you want, but this should put you on the right track. ;-)

Comment: this is much better than my solution with select into #tmp drop table #tmp

Comment: That would definitely work, but CTEs tend to be easier to write and understand. That's why I like them so much. They're also way more efficient that using a subquery because it makes it impossible to get weird behavior with the extra joins and lookups.